# Exclude based on sub-table's value

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the table Audit, and AuditStatus.
Where auditId in AuditStatus is a foreign key, mapping the pk of table Audit.

```
table Audit
id    | auditName   |
1     | test        |
2     | fooTest     |
3     | barTest     |
```

```
table AuditStatus
id  | auditId | status    | 
11  | 1       | started   |
12  | 1       | completed |
13  | 2       | started   |
```

How can I only select the entries of table Audit, which do not have a AuditStatus.status 'completed'.

The result in this case would be:

```
2     | fooTest     |   
3     | barTest     |
```

I have updated the question and the result example, to make it more clear. The relation Audit -> AuditStatus is a one to many. And I want to exclude the Audits which have a refrerence to an AuditStatus with status 'complete'

Comment: Use `WHERE NOT EXISTS (...)` or `WHERE audit_id NOT IN (...)`.

Comment: `WHERE NOT EXISTS` is preferred - especially if the amount of `AuditStatus.auditId` dups is high and the index `AuditStatus(auditId, status)` exists.

Comment: I'm having a hard time creating the actual sql. Can you please provide me with an rudimentary example. That would be most appreciated.

Comment: Tried the manual? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

Comment: Yes I have, when i use the sql `SELECT * from Audit a
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
 (SELECT null 
  FROM AuditStatus s
  WHERE a.id = s.auditId 
  AND s.status != completed
  )`
I still get 
`1     | test        |`  in the  results, so clearly I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should post your attempted query into your question, not as comment. Anyway, your query is actually correct but your condition is incorrect. Let's inspect your query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Audit a 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT s.auditId
        FROM AuditStatus s
       WHERE a.id = s.auditId AND s.status != 'completed'
);
```

You're suppose to find where the status is not complete, which is true in the subquery but the problem here is you're doing a `NOT EXISTS` which negates the *correct* result you're getting from the subquery.

This is what your subquery will return:

| id | auditId | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 1 | started |
| 13 | 2 | started |

Then when your `NOT EXIST` negates the `auditId` being returned, you'll get this result instead:

| id | auditName |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | barTest |

Which is correct according to the condition; `auditId=3` wasn't returned in the subquery. What you need to modify is actually very simple, you just need to make the subquery return `status = completed` as true then `NOT EXISTS` will return any `Audit.Id` that doesn't match with the correlated subquery. Therefore:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Audit a 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT s.auditId
        FROM AuditStatus s
       WHERE a.id = s.auditId AND s.status = 'completed'
);
```

And that's it, you should be getting the result you looking for.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8f4754d0e501d7d2efe60b29ac03f61a)

Comment: Thanks! That is very helpful indeed. After your explanation it makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

maybe use a left join like below which only joins on Audit Status on Fk as well as status constraint

```
SELECT * 
FROM Audit A
LEFT JOIN AuditStatus ATS
ON A.id= ATS.auditId AND ATS.Status ='completed'
WHERE AS.auditId IS NULL
```